# Add constraint to OpenMDAO at the driver/prob level

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, openmdao

Is it possible to add a constraint to an OpenMDAO problem? In the following example, I would like to constrain the objective function to lying below `-3.16`. I have imported the sellar problem from another file, `sellar_backend.py`. Is it possible for me to add this constraint without modifying `sellar_backend.py`?

**sellar_backend.py**

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizer, Group, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, Component
from openmdao.api import Newton, ScipyGMRES
class SellarDis1(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 1."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis1, self).__init__()

        # Global Design Variable
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))

        # Local Design Variable
        self.add_param('x', val=0.)

        # Coupling parameter
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)

        # Coupling output
        self.add_output('y1', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """Evaluates the equation
        y1 = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2"""

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        x1 = params['x']
        y2 = params['y2']

        unknowns['y1'] = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Jacobian for Sellar discipline 1."""
        J = {}

        J['y1','y2'] = -0.2
        J['y1','z'] = np.array([[2*params['z'][0], 1.0]])
        J['y1','x'] = 1.0

        return J


class SellarDis2(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 2."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis2, self).__init__()

        # Global Design Variable
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))

        # Coupling parameter
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)

        # Coupling output
        self.add_output('y2', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """Evaluates the equation
        y2 = y1**(.5) + z1 + z2"""

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        y1 = params['y1']

        # Note: this may cause some issues. However, y1 is constrained to be
        # above 3.16, so lets just let it converge, and the optimizer will
        # throw it out
        y1 = abs(y1)

        unknowns['y2'] = y1**.5 + z1 + z2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Jacobian for Sellar discipline 2."""
        J = {}

        J['y2', 'y1'] = .5*params['y1']**-.5

        #Extra set of brackets below ensure we have a 2D array instead of a 1D array
        # for the Jacobian;  Note that Jacobian is 2D (num outputs x num inputs).
        J['y2', 'z'] = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])

        return J

class StateConnection(Component):
    """ Define connection with an explicit equation"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StateConnection, self).__init__()

        # Inputs
        self.add_param('y2_actual', 1.0)

        # States
        self.add_state('y2_command', val=1.0)

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Don't solve; just calculate the residual."""

        y2_actual = params['y2_actual']
        y2_command = unknowns['y2_command']

        resids['y2_command'] = y2_actual - y2_command

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ This is a dummy comp that doesn't modify its state."""
        pass

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """Analytical derivatives."""

        J = {}

        # State equation
        J[('y2_command', 'y2_command')] = -1.0
        J[('y2_command', 'y2_actual')] = 1.0

        return J

class SellarStateConnection(Group):
    """ Group containing the Sellar MDA. This version uses the disciplines
    with derivatives."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarStateConnection, self).__init__()

        self.add('px', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
        self.add('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['z'])

        self.add('state_eq', StateConnection())
        self.add('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes=['x', 'z', 'y1'])
        self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['z', 'y1'])
        self.connect('state_eq.y2_command', 'd1.y2')
        self.connect('d2.y2', 'state_eq.y2_actual')

        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                     z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                  promotes=['x', 'z', 'y1', 'obj'])
        self.connect('d2.y2', 'obj_cmp.y2')

        self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['con1', 'y1'])
        self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['con2'])
        self.connect('d2.y2', 'con_cmp2.y2')

        self.nl_solver = Newton()
        self.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()
```

**example.py**

```
from sellar_backend import *
top = Problem()
top.root = SellarStateConnection()

top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
top.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8

top.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),
                     upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]))
top.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

# This is my best attempt so far at adding a constraint at this level    
top.add('new_constraint', ExecComp('new_con = -3.16 - obj'), promotes=['*'])
top.driver.add_constraint('new_constraint', upper=0.0)

top.driver.add_objective('obj')
top.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)

top.setup()
top.run()

print("\n")
print( "Minimum found at (%f, %f, %f)" % (top['z'][0], \
                                         top['z'][1], \
                                         top['x']))
print("Coupling vars: %f, %f" % (top['y1'], top['d2.y2']))
print("Minimum objective: ", top['obj'])
```

This fails with `AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute 'add'`. It would be very very convenient to add this new constraint at the Problem level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The `add` method is on top.root, not top. You add components to Groups, in this case the root group of the problem.

```
# This is my best attempt so far at adding a constraint at this level
top.root.add('new_constraint', ExecComp('new_con = -3.16 - obj'), promotes=['*'])
top.driver.add_constraint('new_con', upper=0.0)
```

Also, since you promoted '*' in the first line, the quantity you want to constrain is called 'new_con'.

Comment: Thanks! When would I not want to use `promotes=['*']`? It's tempting to always use this and never think about it again.

Comment: `promotes=['*']` is a bit like using `from foobar import *` in Python.  In some contexts its fine, but if your group has a lot of components then your chances of having unintended consequences increases.  In some situations you do want to expose all of a components parameters and unknowns to the parent group boundary, just be careful that there aren't unintended name conflicts when you do so.

Comment: to add to what @RobFalck said, while `promote=['*]` is pretty convenient it can cause some problems. First, you can get unexpected connections, but if you're careful this is avoidable. More problematic though is when you share your model with someone else. In that case, they can't easily see whats connected to what by looking at your file. The latter problem can be somewhat mitigated by using our new model viewer, but its still not super great practice: http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usr-guide/tutorials/visualizing-model-connections.html